# Split-Panel AJAX-Enabled ASP .NET MVC 5 Application With History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, history.js

I'm trying to use ASP .NET MVC 5 to create a Web application where I have a 'main' page split into two panes.

[image: Page structure, two divs with links that can change their own content or the other div's.]

Each of these two panes is supposed to show `PartialViews` (sometimes lists, sometimes data, almost like a master-detail flow pattern) that may contain links. These links, make `AJAX` calls to get PartialViews from the server and replace the content of one of the panes (either the same one where the link was, or the opposite one). These PartialViews may represent different `ViewModels` and come from different controllers.

I can get this to work by using custom jQuery/Javascript. The links on the PartialViews trigger functions that fetch other PartialViews and replace a Pane's content. My problem arises when I want to allow users to use the browser's back button.

In order to do that for both HTML5 and non HTML5 browsers, I've added [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to my project and configured my application so that it uses pushState() with the fetched data and the url to get it, etc.

```
History.pushState({ 
                    content: [THE_PARTIAL_VIEW], 
                    paneId: [THE_ID_OF_THE_PANE_TO_REPLACE], 
                    paneUrl : [THE_PATH_TO_GET_THE_PARTIAL_VIEW] 
                  }, 
                  title,
                  [THE_URL_TO_SHOW_IN_THE_BROWSER_BAR]);
```

Given that:

- The main page is delivered by the `HomeController' and that all other PartialViews are delivered by other Controllers;
- Those .cshtml files are stored under `Views/CONTROLER_NAME`;
- I want the user to be able to use back/forward button navigation;
- I want the user to be able to, for example, bookmark or refresh the `[THE_URL_TO_SHOW_IN_THE_BROWSER_BAR]` and get the main page with the corresponding panes;

my main issue is being able to capture the 'state' of a page, represented by the information in panels 1 and 2 which may come from different `Actions` in different `Controllers`, in a url.

**What is the recommended approach for me to 'build' the `[THE_URL_TO_SHOW_IN_THE_BROWSER_BAR]` url that shows on the browser's top bar and for my application to understand that url (in case the user saves/refreshes/sends it) and deliver a main page with the appropriate panels, taking into account that their contents may come from different Controllers**?

### My Suggested Approach...

is to use the `HomeController` all the time to deliver the main page and then have the other Controllers contain the Actions for returning PartialViews.

HomeController would then have a "Main" Action that can take parameters detailing the names (possibly shortened) of the controller/action/etc. needed for making the left and right pane. The "Main" action would then return the main `View` with a ViewModel containing those attributes and then Razor would render the necessary Partials using `Html.RenderAction(...)` and the received parameters.

My javascript should keep track of what's being displayed on each pane and update the url's parameters accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there were no answers/comments, my Suggested Approach is to use the `HomeController` all the time to deliver the main page (`MainView`) and then have the other `Controllers` contain the `Actions` for returning the different `PartialViews`.

`HomeController` has a `"Main"` `Action` that can take parameters detailing the names (possibly shortened) of the controller/action/etc. needed for making the left and right pane. The "Main" action returns the main `View` with a `ViewModel` containing those attributes and then Razor renders the necessary Partials using `Html.RenderAction(...)` and the received parameters.

My `javascript` keeps track of what's being displayed on each pane and update the url's parameters accordingly.